# Swagger UI oauth cookie interfering with Spring boot security oauth?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, swagger-ui, openapi

I added springdoc-openapi-ui 1.6.12 in my Spring Boot project. I configured oAuth2 with PKCE and everything works fine, when I click on the "authorize" button it redirects me to a sso connection page. Then, I can send requests via swagger ui.

The problem is that it interferes with my Angular front end authentication. The front loops on the /login rout, with a 401 error. Swagger oauth uses the same session cookie as Spring Security/Angular.

Is there a way to use the same session for swagger ui AND angular ? Or is the problem somewhere else ?

This is my configuration :

```
    springdoc:
      swagger-ui:
        path: /api-docs
        tagsSorter: alpha
        oauth:
          clientId: "XXX"
          clientSecret: "XXX"
          use-pkce-with-authorization-code-grant: true
      oAuthFlow:
        authorizationUrl: "XXX/as/authorization.oauth2"
        tokenUrl: "XXX/as/token.oauth2"
        scope : XXX profile groups XXX email
```

edit :

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())
                .and().csrf().disable()

                .headers()
                .frameOptions().disable()
                .httpStrictTransportSecurity()
                .includeSubDomains(false)
                .maxAgeInSeconds(60*60*24*5)
                .and().and()

                .authorizeRequests(a -> a
                        // Management endpoints
                        .antMatchers(
                                "/health" + MATCH_ALL,
                                "/info",
                                "/prometheus",
                                "/loggers" + MATCH_ALL,
                                "/metrics" + MATCH_ALL
                        ).permitAll()

                        // Authentication
                        .antMatchers(Routes.CURRENT_USER).permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/oauth2/authorization/XXX").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers(Routes.LOGIN).authenticated()

                        // Preflight requests
                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()

                        // Applications
                        .antMatchers(Routes.XXX.BASE + MATCH_ALL).hasAuthority(AuthorityUtil.AUTHORITY_XXX)
                )

                // By setting the login page here, Spring won't ask which provider we want to use
                .oauth2Login().loginPage("/oauth2/authorization/XXX")
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::opaqueToken)
        ;
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.applyPermitDefaultValues();
        config.setAllowedOriginPatterns(List.of("*"));
        config.setAllowedMethods(List.of("*"));
        config.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.setMaxAge(1800L);

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration(MATCH_ALL, config);
        return source;
    }
```

Comment: Did you configure your spring REST API security with `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` or `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client`? Which OAuth2 client library did you use in Angular app?

Comment: I use both server and client. In Angular, I use auth-sign

Comment: And what does your SecurityFilterChain(s) look like?

Comment: Also, do you have any link to auth-sign? I don't know about this Angular lib and first search results are not relevant.

Comment: Last what are the versions of your dependencies spring-boot, spring-security)?